# Unknown error message in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, error, zsh

When I open the Terminal I keep getting this message, which I suppose is some error:

> /Users/sinisasasic/.zshrc:export:48: not valid in this context: 
>   Support/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Can anybody help me in translating what this exactly means and what should I do to resolve it, if it’s some problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.zshrc is a file run when you start an interactive zsh shell, found in your home directory. The error message says you have an export command which is written incorrectly on line 48. `not valid in this context` means you're trying to export something that's not a variable. It looks like you're trying to add stuff to your PATH, but are substituting the current path inside the zshrc file. Check that line in the file, there's probably a line along the lines of:

```
export $PATH=/some/directory/to/add/to/path/:$PATH
```

You just need to remove the first `$` because it's substituting the current path there instead of assigning the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=/some/directory/to/add/to/path/:$PATH
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394367/zsh-error-export54-not-valid-in-this-context

Comment: I changed the line per your suggestion however the problem persists — it still shows the same message with 2 new error messages added:
/Users/sinisasasic/.zshrc:export:48: not valid in this context: Support/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
/Users/sinisasasic/.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/sinisasasic/.rvm/scripts/rvm:14: command not found: ps

Comment: @SinišaŠašić Can you give the text of your .zshrc file around line 48 and the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Lines 47–50 from the .zshrc file:  
# Customize to your needs...  
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/sinisasasic/Library/Application Support/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin  
  
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting  
  
(I did change $PATH to PATH per your suggestion, but I reverted everything back after seeing the same error message)…  
  
The output of echo $PATH:  
  
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/sinisasasic/Library/Application:/Users/sinisasasic/.rvm/bin

Comment: @SinišaŠašić I see the problem. In the first line, you have Application Support The space is screwing it up. You can escape it by putting Application\ Support instead, but having spaces in paths can screw things up in some cases, so it may be better to make a symlink of that directory to a path without spaces.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge… To conclude, should I first do this: ln -s ~/Application\ Support/ ApplicationSupport, and then use the ApplicationSupport symlink I created in here: export PATH=$PATH:/Users/sinisasasic/Library/ApplicationSupport/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin, and with(out) the '$' before PATH?

Comment: @SinišaŠašić Close, but your link command is wrong, try: `ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support ~/Library/ApplicationSupport` The export line looks okay.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I just wonder… how come error message’s gone even if the export PATH has $ sign in front of it (export PATH=$PATH:/Users/sinisasasic/Library/ApplicationSupport/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin)? What’s changed?

Comment: The second `PATH` should have a $. Basically, putting a $ makes it substitute the current value of that variable instead of referring to the actual variable. The first `PATH` has no $ because you're trying to assign the variable, the second has a $ because you want to append those paths to the existing paths in the variable. e.g. if the value of `PATH` is `/usr/bin`, then `echo $PATH` will print `/usr/bin` but `echo PATH` just prints `PATH` because it's just a name, the $ resolves the variable to its value.